# Image Not Showing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried to fetch data from API and some other data was fetched correctly but not image. The image is not showing how can I solve this?

This is my model:

```
class Album {
  final int temp;
  final int hum, pres, clouds;
  final String msg, cityname;
  List<String> weatherDescriptions;
  List<String> weatherIcons;

  Album(
      {this.weatherDescriptions,
      this.temp,
      this.cityname,
      this.clouds,
      this.hum,
      this.weatherIcons,
      this.msg,
      this.pres});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      weatherDescriptions: List<String>.from(
          json['current']["weather_descriptions"].map((x) => x)),

      temp: json['current']['temperature'],
      cityname: json['request']['query'],
      // desc: json['weather'][0]['description']
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "weather_descriptions":
            List<dynamic>.from(weatherDescriptions.map((x) => x)),
      };
}
```

this is my code

```
FutureBuilder<Album>(
              future: futureAlbum,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("${snapshot.data.cityname}"),
                        Text("${snapshot.data.temp}"),
                        Text("${snapshot.data.weatherDescriptions.join(',')}"),
Image.network("${snapshot.data.weatherIcons}"),

                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
             return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
```

Comment: as @Alex mentioned, there is no widget for image in your code.

Comment: what is the output of `print(snapshot.data.weatherIcons)` in your builder?

Comment: weatherIcon Is Image

Comment: You're trying to set a lots of Strings into an Image. It will be something like snapshot.data.weathetIcons[0] to get one or to make a for loop of images to get every single index.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing an image anywhere. You can use `Image.network` ([Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image)) to load an image from the network. You need to add the path for the image into your data structure.

Please check if the URL (stored in `snapshot.data.weatherIcons`) you try to fetch is actually accessible. You can just open it in a browser of your choice. If you see the image or get a prompt to download, we can take the next step.

Comment: I forgot to add image code line in question but image not showing How can i Solve??

Comment: Can you check if the path you get, is accessible? You can just open it in a browser of your choice.

Comment: Image path is Correct

Comment: @jayprajapati: Can you share the data of `snapshot`